# jquery function property doesn't recognize @Model.EndDate value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, entity-framework, countdowntimer

First and foremost here is the link to the countdown timer I am using: 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Slim-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-with-jQuery-DownCount.html

I am using Visual Studio, c# MVC ASP.NET, Entity Framework, bootstrap & razor for cshtml pages and jquery.

It works fine if I set the date manually like this:

```
<script>
  $('.countdown').downCount({
    date: '06/06/2015 12:00:00',
    offset: +1
  });
</script>
```

However, I need to call an object from the Entity Framework, get the EndDate from said object and use that to set the countdown timer. 
So I tried calling the object like this (inside my HTML page):

```
$('.countdown').downCount({
    date: '@Model.EndDate',
    offset: +1
});
```

Apparently, the property just doesn't recognize the @Model.EndDate value I'm trying to pass, and just sees it as a null value. How do I make it recognize the value?

Comment: you have @Model.EndDate in the browser?

Comment: I realised it's not actually a format problem, it just doesn't read the data. :( And I have no clue why that is. 

the html page uses: @model Domain.Module.Agenda.AgendaSettingsModule

So I call the model to get the current module (which is called through routing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make another property call `StrEndDate` do your formatting of the date and set it to this property on the server then send it down as a string, so js doesnt interfere with the date values.

Answer (score 0):

It might not like AM/PM, but using this:

```
function whatever() {
        alert('@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")')
    }
```

I got this:

```
function whatever() {
    alert('05/15/2015 10:40:34')
}
```

Reference for formatting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx